# Calculate the number of input sequences that could result in the same state of hash table

Tags: hashtable

I encountered this problem while preparing for a test.
A hash table of length 10 uses open addressing with hash function `h(k)=k mod 10`, and linear probing. After inserting 6 values into an empty hash table,
the table is as shown below

```
0 |
1 |
2 | 42
3 | 23
4 | 34
5 | 52
6 | 46
7 | 33
8 |
9 |
```

How many different insertion sequences of the key values using the same hash
function and linear probing will result in the hash table shown above?

(A) 10  (B) 20  (C) 30       (D) 40

Answer given in Solutions: c

Could someone please explain how the answer is to be calculated? TIA

Answer (score 5):

Since, **33 mod 10 = 3** and it is stored in **7th** position, we know that it must have come after 23,34,52,46 and as 52 came before 33 hence, so did 42 (same hash value). We've established that **33** comes *last* in the sequences.

For the rest of the numbers there are 2 cases :

(1) Considering 52 came after 42,23,34 (as they are stored according to their hash value) which can be rearranged in 3! ways. That means 52 came **4th** position and 46 came in 5th.

(2) Considering 52 came after 42,23,34,46 which can be rearranged in 4! ways. That means 52 came at **5th** position.

So, total number of insertion sequences = 4! + 3! = 30

Answer (score 2):

In a valid insertion sequence, the elements 42, 23 and 34 should appear before 52 and 33, and 46 must appear before 33.
Here number of different sequences = 3! x 5 = 30
In the above expression, 3! is for elements 42, 23 and 34 as they can appear in any order, and 5 is for element 46 as it can appear at 5 different places.